Optimize Looker Dashboard to reduce number of queries to BigQuery
I have created a looker dashboard and it works fine but costs a lot.
Upon looking into it, here seems to be the problem.
There is a single table in BigQuery which is the data source. It is 2.64GB in size (3M rows and around 115 columns). It's extensive and historical.
In the dashboard, I created 18 different filters/controls and 1 chart.
Turns out every time I add a filter in the dashboard, it is running a separate query for each of those controls. Each of those queries cost around 400MB avg. Today morning when I checked sales of a single product, it ran 16 queries for a total 5GB billed bytes. That's gonna cost me more than my salary (I pay out of pocket)
When I put a filter on Brand, it filters every other control as well. If I filter "XYZ" Brand, the control in Manufacturer updates to show only manufacturers of that brand and how much sales. Seller control updates to show sellers of that brand and respective sales. city filter updates to show cities where that brand had sales and how much. See example here.
Here's my alternative approach:
I create another FILTER table that only has distinct values for each of the 18 filters. column 1 has brands. Column 2 has categories. Column 3 has mfacs. column 4 has cities. That would come out to be around 50MB or so. Probably less.
Then I create the filters/controls using this FILTER table. Once I select all the filters, there should be a button to click on refresh the chart.
The chart will have the Main Table as the data source and will run the query based on the filters selected.
This should Ideally allow me around 2K queries for 1 TiB (500Mb per query). Assuming we hit 5K queries, I will be charged $20 or less per month which is fine by me. That's my 1 day salary (India).
Have heard about partitioning but not sue if it will help since I want month-on-month sales view for all months.
But I am not sure if this is possible. Pls tell me if it's possible and if yes, a rough roadmap of how to achieve it?

Yes, best practise is to use the date as partition. Setting the filter can be done for one month or so. In the final step change the date to the desired maximum range.

@Samuel
I tried that and it has improved a bit with both partitioning and clustering. But the main issue remains. All these controls are linked/grouped together. Any selection in one means 15 queries initiated for each of the controls. I ungrouped them but then the chart itself won't filter.
